# Evento 'input' só acontecendo ao carregar a página

Tags: javascript, jquery, aplicação-web, javascript-eventos

Olá, pessoal do StackOverflow.

Tento fazer com que um textarea de uma página web que estou desenvolvendo verifique continuamente se o texto digitado é igual ou diferente de um frase pré-definida, conforme o código em javascript e jquery abaixo:

```
var atualiza = function(){

var texto = $(".campo-digitacao").text();
var frase = $(".frase").text();

if (texto==frase){

    console.log("TEXTO IGUAL");

    } else if (texto!=frase){

    console.log("TEXTO DIFERENTE");

    }

console.log("escreveu");
}


$(".campo-digitacao").on('input',atualiza());
```

No entanto, eu só fico com duas notificações via console ("TEXTO DIFERENTE" e "escreveu"), como se o evento 'input' só acontecesse uma vez, ao carregar a página, ao invés dele executar toda vez que o texto do "campo-digitação" muda.
Tentei utilizar outros eventos, como 'textchange' e 'change', mas continuo na mesma situação.

Answer (score 3):

Uma opção poderia ser obter o valor direto do elemento sem precisar armazenar em uma variável:

```js
var frase = 'TESTE';

$(".campo-digitacao").on('input', atualiza);

function atualiza() {
  if (this.value == frase) {
    console.log("TEXTO IGUAL");
  } else {
    console.log("TEXTO DIFERENTE");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="campo-digitacao"></textarea>
```

E o correto é usar `.on('input',atualiza);` ao invés de `.on('input',atualiza());` para que o escopo seja transferido para a função e que ela seja invocada sempre que ocorrer o evento, e não somente uma vez.

Comment: Nem tinha reparado que o `.on()` era o mesmo elemento :) Bem apanhado. Podes juntar um comentário ao problema `.on('input',atualiza());`? assim fica completa a resposta `+1`

Comment: Obrigado @Sergio

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o evento [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/).

```
$(".campo-digitacao").on('change', atualiza);
```

Ou também o evento [keyup](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) bindando no input.

```
$(".campo-digitacao").bind('keyup', atualiza);
```

Comment: A funcão `bind` está descontinuada e não é mais interessante utilizá-la.